# How to model change trends?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am dealing with a classification problem.
I need to model the changing trends of the features.

For example,I have some characteristic changes as follows.

Feature1(Positive)：
[image]

Feature2(Negative)：
[image]

How to model change trends of those characteristics?

Comment: Approximate the trend using e.g. OLS and use the coefficients as predictors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the empirical derivative.

I.e.  x.delay(some small value) - x